# How can I see the data of postgres database configured inside the docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, client

I am currently using the docker to run the Laravel project with a Postgres database. I created a separate container for PHP and Postgres. I created the docker network to communicate with both of them. Now I want to see the data inside my Postgres database via any client?

Can I do that? If yes please suggest the client and configurations required

I have already tried client images by docker but not helpful.

Comment: How would you examine the data without Docker involved?  The same techniques like using a `psql` client to connect to the database will work just fine if the database is running inside a Docker container.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/app-psql.html) inside your container.  From the command-line, run a command similar to this:

```
docker exec -it container_name psql -U postgres database_name
```

Replace container_name and database_name with the names of your container and database.  If you are using a different user, change out the username as well.